# RxSwift - block/stop/ignore event if condition met

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

After filtering an Observable list, I might have an empty list.  I'm only interested in events that contain a populated list.  Is there any way to stop empty events propagating to `onNext`?

```
        let source: BehaviorRelay<[Int]> = .init(value: [])

        source
            .map { nums -> [Int] in
                return nums.filter { $0 < 10 }
            }
            /// What can go here to stop/block/ignore an empty list
            .subscribe(onNext: { nums in
               print("OKPDX \(nums)")
            })

        source.accept([1, 9, 13])
        // prints "[1, 9]" (all good)

        source.accept([20, 22, 101])
        // prints "[]" (not desirable, I'd rather not know)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `.filter`? You could do this:

```swift
.map { nums -> [Int] in
        return nums.filter { $0 < 10 }
     }
.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
```

Or you could also validate that whenever you get an event like this:

```swift
.subscribe(onNext: { nums in
      guard !nums.isEmpty else { return }
      print("OKPDX \(nums)")
})
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after, thanks